# Brown discharge from horse's eye

Tags: horses, infections

I accept this will be extremely difficult to advise on without images but I wanted to post this before I left work. (mostly so I won't forget.) Will add pictures when I get home.

My horse has started to get thick brown discharge from her left eye. She has no other physical/visible clues. E.G no redness, no black spots (other than her natural mottling.)
She did have some in her right eye but no where near as much.

I'm hoping it's just a mix of general dirt from her environment that has disturbed her eye.

In which case I'll be doing a spring clean over the next few weeks so that should hopefully sort it out if it's just dust/grime/mold etc.

Update: Unfortunately she wasn't standing still long enough yesterday for the flash but I'll try again tonight.

In the meantime this is a good representation
[image]

Comment: Can you post a pic of it?

Comment: @YvetteColomb - Posted! Not my mare as she wouldn't stand for the flash but I've borrowed an image from google that is strikingly similar.

Comment: my horses get things like this and I wipe them away with my hands believe it or not - but you can use a wash cloth. I've never regarded it as a problem. I am not sure what causes it, if I find out more, I'll write an answer. I must answer some of your other posts.